# Expose MSK serverless cluster to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kafka

I followed the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html guide, but the `Properties → Network settings → Edit public access` option doesn't appear at all. Could it be that it only applies to provisioned clusters? Or I might be missing something?